# Canvacord.rank is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

When I run the command "!rank", an error message is displayed on the terminal :

**TypeError: Canvacord.rank is not a function**

Version of canvacord 5.0.8

```
    let img = await Canvacord.rank({
        username: user.username,
        discrim: user.discriminator,
        status: user.presence.status,
        currentXP: xp.toString(),
        neededXP: xpNeeded.toString(),
        rank,
        level,
        avatarURL: user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png"}),
        color: "white"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a subtle typo: [looking at their documentation](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Rank), it seems that "Rank" Must be capitalized:

```
   let img = await Canvacord.Rank({
        username: user.username,
        discrim: user.discriminator,
        status: user.presence.status,
        currentXP: xp.toString(),
        neededXP: xpNeeded.toString(),
        rank,
        level,
        avatarURL: user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png"}),
        color: "white"
    })
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks you a lot men ... Have a new error : The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream. :(

Comment: The problem is that :         message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageAttachment(img, "rank.png"))

Comment: If you want to open a separate question on this error, it could be useful. The commented code seems unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Canvacord#Rank** is a class so based on **[examples](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/examples/rank)**, it should be something like this:

```js
const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png"}))
    .setCurrentXP(xp)
    .setRequiredXP(xpNeeded)
    .setStatus(user.presence.status)
    .setUsername(user.username)
    .setDiscriminator(user.discriminator)
    .setRank(rank)
    .setLevel(level)

rank.build()
    .then(buffer => {
        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(buffer, "RankCard.png");
        message.channel.send(attachment);
    });
```